# Consume Realex JSON request -Spring MVC, Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I need some help with writing a controller to consume a JSON response from a payment system (Realex).

So far, I have the following from the Realex documentation but can't figure out how to write the controller - i'm new to Spring Boot/Spring MVC.

```
RealexHpp realexHpp = new RealexHpp("Shared Secret");
HppResponse hppResponse = realexHpp.responseFromJson(responseJson);
// responseJson will be the Java variable containing the JSON response string
String result = hppResponse.getResult();
String message = hppResponse.getMessage();
String authCode = hppResponse.getAuthCode();
```

So far, i have written:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.realexpayments.hpp.sdk.RealexHpp;
import com.realexpayments.hpp.sdk.domain.HppResponse;

@Controller
public class PaymentController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/enrolment/confirmation", method = RequestMethod.GET,  consumes = "text/plain")
public String process(@RequestBody String responseJson, Model model) throws Exception {

    RealexHpp realexHpp = new RealexHpp("secret");
    HppResponse hppResponse = realexHpp.responseFromJson(responseJson);
    // responseJson will be the Java variable containing the JSON response string
    String result = hppResponse.getResult();
    String message = hppResponse.getMessage();
    String authCode = hppResponse.getAuthCode();

    System.out.println("Result: "+result);
    System.out.println("Message: "+message);
    System.out.println("AuthCode: "+authCode);

    model.addAttribute("result", result);
    model.addAttribute("message", message);
    model.addAttribute("authcode", authCode);

    return "enrolment/confirmation";

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the specific problem you're running into with writing your controller?

Are you not receiving any data on the view side?

Is there an error being thrown?

Is it not behaving the way you expect?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/enrolment/process", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String process(@RequestBody String responseJson, Model model) throws Exception { 

  System.out.println("responseJson: "+responseJson);   
  model.addAttribute("message", responseJson);  
  return "enrolment/confirmation";

  }

Comment: I've managed to receive data as a String but I want to be able to bind it to "HppResponse hppResponse = realexHpp.responseFromJson(responseJson);" 

Everytime I do this I get a null error... i'm thinking of passing the string via a service layer and then saving the response in a database... 

A cant seem to bind it to another object because the JSON identifiers are in CAPITALS... :-) odd

Comment: what does the `responseJson` variable contain?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Spring MVC isn't the right tool here.

See: https://github.com/realexpayments/rxp-hpp-java

It's expecting you to use their SDK to generate the repsonseJson:

```
HppRequest hppRequest = new HppRequest()
                    .addAmount(100)
                    .addCurrency("EUR")
                    .addMerchantId("merchantId");
```

RealexHpp realexHpp = new RealexHpp("mySecret");
String requestJson = realexHpp.requestToJson(hppRequest);

You might want to be using Spring MVC to capture the parameters for the request.